# error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected unity 3d game engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script file

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playermove : MonoBehaviour{
public float moveSpeed=5f;}


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        jump();
       Vector3 movment = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0f ,0f);
       transform.position += movment * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; 
    }
    void jump() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("jump"));
        gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();AddForce(new Vector2(0f,5f),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}

}
```

And I am getting this error:

> error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>   unity 3d game engine

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly is the problem? There's two unmatched close brackets (`}`) for a start.

Comment: remove } from public float moveSpeed=5f;}, and the last }.  And then your question

Answer (score 0):

Your coding file has a bracket issue.

```
 public float moveSpeed=5f;}
```

It should be like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playermove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        jump();
        Vector3 movment = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movment * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    void jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("jump")) ;
        gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>(); AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}
```